# Calling method of SignalR Client from a SignalR Server is not returning results

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, signalr

Pretty fresh to the ASP.NET / ASP.NET Core environments (typically work in WinForms using DevExpress), and having a bit of a problem trying to understand and implement a SignalR server that calls methods on the client. From my understanding of the "Client Results" section of this [Using Hubs in SignalR article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-results), I should be able to call some methods on the client from the server. This works in most cases; however, when I try to call a method on the client that takes in parameters and returns a result, I get an error: `System.Exception: 'Client didn't provide a result.'`, which I cannot seem to find much info on.

My server in this case is a basic ASP.NET Core application targeting .NET 7 (so `<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>` in the .csproj), and my client is a WinForms application targeting .NET 7 Windows (`net7.0-windows`) and using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` NuGet package (v 7.0.7 as of writing).

My intention is to eventually have a WinForms "SignalR Server" that can communicate with a variety of clients, but use one connected client as the "Primary Client". I haven't built any of that code yet, so I'm just using my first connected client as the "Primary Client".

Here's my server-side code (using a strongly-typed hub):

```
public interface IStrongServer
{
    Task<Boolean> TestBoolean();
    Task<Boolean> TestBooleanWithParameters(string toSend);
}

public class StrongServerHub : Hub<IStrongServer>
{
    private readonly StrongServer _StrongServer;

    public StrongServerHub(StrongServer nStrongServer)
    {
        _StrongServer = nStrongServer;
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        _StrongServer.AssignPrimaryConnection(this.Context.ConnectionId);
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
    {
        _StrongServer.DisconnectPrimaryConnection(this.Context.ConnectionId);
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}

public class StrongServer : IStrongServer
{
    private string PrimaryConnectionId = "";
    private bool PrimaryConnected = false;

    private IHubContext<StrongServerHub, IStrongServer> Hub
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public StrongServer(IHubContext<StrongServerHub, IStrongServer> hub)
    {
        Hub = hub;
    }

    public void AssignPrimaryConnection(string connectionId)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PrimaryConnectionId))
        {
            PrimaryConnectionId = connectionId;
            PrimaryConnected = true;
        }
    }

    public void DisconnectPrimaryConnection(string connectionId)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PrimaryConnectionId) && String.Equals(PrimaryConnectionId, connectionId))
        {
            PrimaryConnectionId = "";
            PrimaryConnected = false;
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> TestBoolean()
    {
        return await Hub.Clients.Client(PrimaryConnectionId).TestBoolean();
    }

    public async Task<bool> TestBooleanWithParameters(string ToSend)
    {
        return await Hub.Clients.Client(PrimaryConnectionId).TestBooleanWithParameters(ToSend);
    }
}

public class SignalRHost
{
    public StrongServer Server { get; set; }

    public void Run()
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
        builder.Services.AddSignalR();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<StrongServer>();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapRazorPages();
        app.MapHub<StrongServerHub>("/strong");

        Server = app.Services.GetService<StrongServer>();

        app.RunAsync();

    }
}

// Then in Program.cs, I'd do:
SignalRHost host = new SignalRHost();
host.Run();

bool returnedBoolean = await host.Server.TestBoolean();
bool returnedBooleanWithParameters = await host.Server.TestBooleanWithParameters("Hello World!");
```

And here's my client-side code:

```
public interface ITestClient
{
    bool TestBoolean();
    bool TestBooleanWithParameters(string test);
}

using System.Diagnostics;
public class SignalRClient : ITestClient
{
    HubConnection TestConnection = null;

    public async void Init()
    {
        TestConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://localhost:5035/strong").Build(); // The port 5035 is what my machine used.

        TestConnection.On(nameof(TestBoolean), TestBoolean);
        TestConnection.On<string>(nameof(TestBooleanWithParameters), (p1) => TestBooleanWithParameters(p1));

        await TestConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    public bool TestBoolean()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool TestBooleanWithParameters(string test)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"TestBooleanReturn: {test}"); ;
        return true;
    }
}

internal static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        SignalRClient client = new SignalRClient();
        client.Init();
        
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}
```

Again, the differences between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core are confusing enough to me, so my first thought was that it could be a

**TLDR:** Is expecting results from a client not possible if the client method has parameters? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Core was developed so that same code would run on Windows, Linux, Mac without changes.  So Net library was reorganized so same interface would work on all three OS.  You are making an HTTP Request and should get back a HTTP Response with a status of 200 OK.  Error indicated the connection never completed because not response was return.  When a connection completes you should get back 200 response of a 400/500 error status.  No response either means 1) IP is no good or server is not running 2) HTTPS - TLS is failing 3) You are using a Proxy and proxy is failing. 4) Connection is closing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jdweng's comment about the HTTP Request pointed me in the direction of logging the communication between the client and the server. I added both server-side and client-side logging [as found in this Logging and Diagnostics article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and found that I was getting an error on the client-side: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection: Warning: Failed to find a value returning handler for TestBooleanWithParameters`.

After seeing some other comments across StackOverflow and Github, I realized that I had to change the following line:

```
TestConnection.On<string>(nameof(TestBooleanWithParameters), (p1) => TestBooleanWithParameters(p1));
```

And change it to:

```
TestConnection.On(nameof(TestBooleanWithParameters), (String p1) => TestBooleanWithParameters(p1));
```

Now everything is working and I'm not longer receiving errors.

Answer (score 1):

I want to provide a different answer where you can keep the typed arguments and where you pass an `Action<T>` instead of a `Func<T>`.

So instead of

```
TestConnection.On<string>(nameof(TestBooleanWithParameters), (p1) => TestBooleanWithParameters(p1));
```

you need to use an `Action` parameter instead of a `Func`

```
TestConnection.On<string>(nameof(TestBooleanWithParameters), TestBooleanWithParameters);
```

For references, there are different overloads for `HubConnection.On()` in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnectionExtensions`.

- [HubConnectionExtensions.cs at Gitbub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/SignalR/clients/csharp/Client.Core/src/HubConnectionExtensions.cs)
- [HubConnectionExtensions.On Method at https://learn.microsoft.com/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client.hubconnectionextensions.on?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

You were using this one:

```
public static IDisposable On(this HubConnection hubConnection, string methodName, Func<Task> handler)
{
    ArgumentNullThrowHelper.ThrowIfNull(hubConnection);

    return hubConnection.On(methodName, Type.EmptyTypes, args => handler());
}
```

My solution uses this overload

```
public static IDisposable On<T1>(this HubConnection hubConnection, string methodName, Action<T1> handler)
{
    ArgumentNullThrowHelper.ThrowIfNull(hubConnection);

    return hubConnection.On(methodName,
        new[] { typeof(T1) },
        args => handler((T1)args[0]!));
}
```